# Responsive images css not responding

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

Hello guys I have placed a image in css and its working fine Here is the code:

```
<div class="r-img" ></div>
```

and the css

```
 .r-img {
background-image: url(./img/cloud2.png);
background-size: 30%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 439;
margin-left: 4%;
margin-top: 0%;
}
```

Here is the print screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5Ulp.jpg

When I use CTRL+Scrool or i change the resolution everything is perfect the image stays there

I want to add more images but it doesnt fix intro the page even if i use exactly the same css as the first image. Take a look.

```
    <div class="tel" ></div>
```

and the css

```
.tel {
background-image: url(./img/sms-6-256.png);
background-size: 30%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
overflow: hidden;
margin-left: 4%;
margin-top: 0%;
}
```

exactly the same.

The image is added but when I change the resolution or I zoom in the image moves:

[image]

Any ideea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a fiddle that has more of your HTML in it, it's a little hard to say, but if you have a containing element (a div, or something else) that holds the first working image, put the second image in it, and set your CSS to something like:

```
background-image:url(firstimage.png),url(secondimage.png);
background-position:4% 0%,40% 40%;
background-size:30%,5%;
```

A comma separated group of values will put two images in the same element these styles will apply to. All of these comma separated values will be for their respective images. That is, the first value will apply only to the first image, and the second will apply only to the second image.

Using the `background-position`, you can do more or less what you've done with the margin in this case. I put 40% for the second two values, but you can adjust as necessary. Same with the size.

This should keep it in place, but I haven't tested with a fiddle.

Comment: I see what you are trying to tell me. I inserted both images in 1 css and did exactly what you said. The problem persists. The first image is fixed and the second moves when i change the resolution

Comment: Actually this is working. I added the second image in the first images div and the image it`s fixed. Thank you very much. i really appreciate! `background-image: url(./img/cloud2.png),url(./img/sms-6-256.png);`

Comment: No worries! Also, if your img folder is in your site root, you don't need to add the . to the url. Just begin the path with / to signify the site root.